# Wifi not found! on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wireless

I have recently moved from wired LAN to wireless, so the problem is I have plugged my wifi adapter but It's showing Wifi adapter not found in Settings. As I'm a new linux user I dont know how to properly install my adapter drivers. I don't even know if my adapter is recognized by the system or not.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180